# mTLS with NGINX & Let's encrypt - 400 The SSL certificate error

Tags: nginx, ssl, mtls

I use nginx and let's encrypt. Server is running on `server.io`.

I need to setup mTLS and therefore I need client certificate as well.

I created another Let's encrypt certificate for `client.io` (I used `certbot`: I created NS entires etc and got private/public key for `client.io`.

I want that `client.io` is the only one who can connect to `server.io`.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name server.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/shared_keys/client.io/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

    location / {
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      return 200 'Hello world $ssl_client_s_dn';
    }
}
```

When I try to connect via:

```
curl -v --cert client.io/cert.pem --key client.io/privkey.pem  https://secure-qa.topkey.io
```

I see this in the response"

```
*   Trying 164.92.108.70:443...
* Connected to server.io (164.92.108.70) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Unknown (8):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* [CONN-0-0][CF-SSL] (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / AEAD-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=server.io
*  start date: Oct  3 06:54:33 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jan  1 06:54:32 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "server.io" matched cert's "server.io"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: server.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.87.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.22.0 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Tue, 03 Oct 2023 11:58:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 224
< Connection: close
<
<html>
<head><title>400 The SSL certificate error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The SSL certificate error</center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.22.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Based on response it actually looks like mTLS is working however I am not sure why am I getting error in the response?

`cat /var/log/nginx/error.log` returns:

```
2023/10/04 08:09:29 [crit] 21844#21844: *1250 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 162.142.125.221, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

nginx setup worked with manually created CA certs so I guess there must be something wrong with idea to use Let's encrypt certificates even thought I read that this should work (ChatGPT). If I can not continue with Let's encrypt which certificate should I then use/buy in order to solve this problem easily?

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want to achieve here. Currently you are trying to use the same certificate to authenticate the server and to authenticate the client. This does not really make sense since a certificate should only authenticate a single party. Moreover this way you share the private key between server and client, even though the private key should be kept private (secret).

Comment: The argument to `curl --cert`  should be the client certificate used for client authentication and not  include the CA certificates you're sending with `--cert /etc/../fullchain.pem`  ; use `--cert /etc/../cert.pem`

Comment: which are both rather convoluted ways of say that the `ssl_client_certificate` inyour config should point to the PEM certificates of the CERTIFICATE AUTHORITIES (CAs) you trust to sign client certificates.  The bundled ones are listed under /etc/ssl/certs on a Ubuntu host near me - but with each CA in a separate file.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Maybe I didn't pick certificate names wisely in the question. I have private and public key for `server.io` and another set of key for `client.io`.

Comment: @HBruijn I tried with `cert.pem` and I am getting same result.

Comment: @knagode: In this case `ssl_client_certificate` should contain the trusted CA which has directly or indirectly (via intermediate) issued the client certificate - not the client certificate itself (except in case of self-signed where client certificate and CA are the same certificate).

Comment: @SteffenUllrich and @symcbean: I added `ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ISRG_Root_X1.pem;` and I am getting same error.

Comment: @knagode: I have no idea what the content of your client.io/fullchain.pem is and if ISRG_Root_X1.pem is the expected root CA for this